# Перевод логики дешифрования с Actionscript w/com.hurlant на C#/BouncyCastle - не могу найти проблему

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript, actionscript-3

*оффтоп: названия лучше не придумал*

Есть декомпильнутое flash-приложение, часть логики которого я хочу использовать в C#.

Для начала приведу подчищенную часть приложения с интересующей логикой:

```
package some_package
{
   import flash.net.URLLoader;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.utils.ByteArray;
   import com.hurlant.util.Hex;
   import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.NullPad;
   import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.IPad;
   import com.hurlant.crypto.Crypto;
   import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.ICipher;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import com.hurlant.crypto.rsa.RSAKey;
   import com.hurlant.util.der.PEM;
   import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
   import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
   import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;

   public class Requester
   {      
      private const P_KEY:String = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "private key line" + "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

      private var _loader:URLLoader;

      var urlReq:URLRequest;

      public function Requester( requestUrl:String )
      {
         super();
         this.urlReq = new URLRequest( requestUrl );
         this.urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
         this._loader = new URLLoader( this.urlReq );
         this._loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this.onReqComplete );
         this._loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
         this._loader.load( this.urlReq );
      }

      private function getEncKey(from:ByteArray) : ByteArray
      {
         var keySize:uint = 128;
         var toReturn:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         from.readBytes( toReturn, 0, keySize );
         return toReturn;
      }

      private function decryptString( toDecrypt:String, key:String ) : String
      {
         var algorithm:String = "simple-blowfish-cbc8";

         var keyReady:* = Hex.toArray( Hex.fromString( key ) );
         var toDecryptReady:* = Hex.toArray( toDecrypt );

         var padder:IPad = new NullPad();

         var cipher:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher( algorithm, keyReady, padder );

         padder.setBlockSize(cipher.getBlockSize());

         cipher.decrypt( toDecryptReady );

         return Hex.toString( Hex.fromArray( toDecryptReady ) );
      }

      public function onReqComplete( ev:Event ) : *
      {
         var sMessage:ByteArray = null;
         var len:uint = 0;
         var sign:ByteArray = null;
         var priv_key:RSAKey = null;
         var dst:ByteArray = null;
         var pwd:String = null;
         var offset:uint = 0;
         var conf_data:String = null;
         var dec:String = null;
         var resultObj:Object = null;
         var event:Event = ev;


        sMessage = ByteArray( event.target.data as ByteArray );
        len = sMessage.length;
        sign = this.getEncKey( sMessage );
        priv_key = PEM.readRSAPrivateKey( this.P_KEY );
        dst = new ByteArray();
        priv_key.decrypt( sign, dst, sign.length );
        pwd = Hex.toString( Hex.fromArray( dst ) );
        offset = String( sign ).length;
        conf_data = String( sMessage ).substr( offset, len - offset );
        dec = this.decryptString( conf_data, pwd );
        resultObj = dec;

        //do smth with decrypted string

        this._loader.close();
        return;
      }
   }
}
```

Теперь опишу, насколько я её понимаю - проблема вполне может быть и в семантике.

В конструкторе инициализируем HTTP клиент с колбеком на успех `onReqComplete` и шлём GET-запрос на указанный параметром URL.

`onReqComplete` получает ответ в виде массива байт (полагаю, без заголовков). После чего берёт первые 128 байт ответа функцией `getEncKey` и дешифрует их приватным ключём RSA из константы `P_KEY`. Используется Pkcs1 padding, [sources](https://github.com/Atmosphere/ActionScript/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/crypto/rsa/RSAKey.as#L124).

Далее начинает происходить нечто странное. Я не уверен, что это что-то значимое; возможно, это бред, порождённый декомпилятором или разработчиком приложения.

Только что расшифрованная часть сообщения конвертируется в строку (только для того, чтобы быть сконвертированной обратно в функции `decryptString`), которая в последствии будет использоваться как ключ в `decryptString`.

Остальная часть сообщения так же конвертируется в строку. Но от неё берётся подстрока, начиная с длины *изначальных **нешифрованных** первых 128 байт, сконвертированных в строку*. Эта подстрока сконвертирется в массив байт и будет расшифровываться в `decryptString`.

Все эти преобразования кажутся мне очень странными. Кроме прочего, у меня не получается воспроизвести функцию AS String(smth:ByteArray) в C#. Строка, получаемая с помощью AS String() из первых 128 байт ответа имеет длину 122 символа и довольно похожа на строки, получаемые при помощи C#
`Encoding.UTF8.GetString`
or
`StreamReader`
, но первый вариант даёт строку из 128 символов, а второй - из 118. Это кажется мне очень странным, подозреваю, что здесь возможна какая-то странная потеря данных.

Поскольку я не понимаю этих конверсий, я попросту беру все байты после 128 для дешифрации **и это может быть моей ошибкой**.

Далее мы идём в функцию `decryptString`.

Она конвертирует ключ и данные обратно в массивы байт. После чего, она пытается расшифровать данные при помощи алгоритма blowfish в режиме CBC IV. Она так же объявляет алгоритм как simple ([lib explanation for "simple"](https://github.com/Atmosphere/ActionScript/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/crypto/Crypto.as#L84)) и что он должен использовать NullPad padder ([который, на самом деле, ничего не делает](https://github.com/Atmosphere/ActionScript/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/crypto/symmetric/NullPad.as#L1)).

В общем-то и всё; как мне кажется - ничего сложного.

Такой C# код у меня получился:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    internal sealed class SomeClass
    {
        private const string _privateRSAKeyString = "private key in PEM format with lines separated by \\n symbol";
        private const int _blowfishBlockSize = 8;

        public async Task<string> AnalyzeAsync()
        {
            byte[] response;
            using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
            {//response is cached for testing purposes
                using ( var fw = new StreamReader( "response.txt", Encoding.UTF8 ) )
                    ( await fw.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait( false ) )
                        .Split( new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
                        .ForEach( b => ms.WriteByte( Byte.Parse( b ) ) );
                ms.Position = 0;
                response = await ms.ReadToNewByteArrayAsync( (int) ms.Length ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            }


            byte[] blowfishSignRSAEncrypted,
                IV,
                blowfishEncryptedData;

            using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( response, false ) )
            {
                blowfishSignRSAEncrypted = await ms.ReadToNewByteArrayAsync( 128 ).ConfigureAwait( false );
                IV = await ms.ReadToNewByteArrayAsync( _blowfishBlockSize ).ConfigureAwait( false );
                ms.Position = 128;
                blowfishEncryptedData = await ms.ReadToNewByteArrayAsync( (int) ( ms.Length - ms.Position ) ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            }

            var rsaEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding( new RsaEngine() );
            using ( var txtreader = new StringReader( _privateRSAKeyString ) )
            {
                var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) new PemReader( txtreader ).ReadObject();
                rsaEngine.Init( false, keyPair.Private );
            }

            byte[] blowfishDecryptedSign = rsaEngine.ProcessBlock( blowfishSignRSAEncrypted, 0, blowfishSignRSAEncrypted.Length );

            var blowfishEngine = new BlowfishEngine();
            var cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher( new CbcBlockCipher( new BlowfishEngine() ) );
            cipher.Init( false, new ParametersWithIV( new KeyParameter( blowfishDecryptedSign ), IV ) );

            var dataDecrypted = cipher.ProcessBytes( blowfishEncryptedData );

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString( dataDecrypted );
        }
    }

    public static async Task<byte[]> ReadToNewByteArrayAsync( this MemoryStream ms, int length )
    {
        byte[] whatIsRightfullyYours = new byte[ length ];
        int offset = 0;
        //Stream.Read* return value is designed to be the way to ensure that you got exactly that much data as you need. IDK if that's true for MemoryStream, so let's check it.
        while ( ( offset += await ms.ReadAsync( whatIsRightfullyYours, offset, length - offset ).ConfigureAwait( false ) ) < length ) ;
    return whatIsRightfullyYours;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что этот код возвращает бессмысленную последовательность символов и я не понимаю, в чём дело.

Буду благодарен любой

## UPD.1

В процессе исследования догадался сделать банальный тест "зашифруй-расшифруй".

Расшифровке (той, что уже представлена чуть выше), восстановить исходную строку не удалось, так что проблема точно в ней (а не в какой-то мифической разнице между работой C# и AS или тёмной магии конвертации строк).

## UPD.2

Предыдущий апдейт есть ложь. Неверны были и шифровка, и дешифровка. В дешифровке шифротекст включал в себя IV (`ms.Position = 128;`). В шифровке же не учитывался вариант, когда размер сообщения не кратен размеру шифроблока, из-за чего исходная строка обрезалась библиотекой, что и приводило к неверному восстановлению исходной строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я не уделил достаточно внимания фрагменту

         `var keyReady:* = Hex.toArray( Hex.fromString( key ) );
         var toDecryptReady:* = Hex.toArray( toDecrypt );`

А именно, тому, что шифротекст перед преобразованием из HEX в массив байт не преобразовывается в HEX из UTF8-строки. Соответственно, проблема была в том, что после (правильной) расшифровки Blowfish-ключа, я пытался расшифровать им неправильное (кодированное в Hex) сообщение.

Достаточным решением является вызов `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders.Hex.Decode(ciphertextWithIV);` до разбиения сообщения на IV и message.

Comment: Не знаю, насколько этот вопрос полезен для stackoverflow, оставлю его здесь на всякий случай. Жалеть об его удалении не стану.